# Encountered "<EOF>" Lucene.net 3.0.3 QueryParser Error

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am getting the error when Search Text Contain 'AND' at the end of phrase.

searchQuery:"Text AND"

```
    private static Query parseQuery(string searchQuery, QueryParser parser)
    {
       Query query;
       try
       {
         query = parser.Parse(searchQuery.Trim());
       }
       catch (ParseException e)
       {
         query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery.Trim()));
       }
       return query;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Updated it covers my All scenario.**

My problem is **solved**. When i get the exception i replace the search query with lowercase latters.

```
searchQuery:"Text AND"
```

after replacing it with lowercase letter it will look like:

```
searchQuery:"text and"
```

It works in my case and cover all my scenarios.

```
 private static Query parseQuery(string searchQuery, QueryParser parser)
 {
    Query query;
    try
    {
      query = parser.Parse(searchQuery);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
      query = null;
    }
    if (query == null)
    {
      string replacedQuery;
      cooked = Regex.Replace(searchQuery, @"\B[A-Z]", m => "" + m.ToString().ToLower());
      cooked = Regex.Replace(cooked, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
      query = parser.Parse(replacedQuery);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Now this solution works for type of queries following below:

- "Text +"
- "Text ="  **Note:** Any special Character at the end of string.
- "Text AND" **Note:** Any Boolean Operator at the end of string.
- "Text AND Data"

  **Note:** Remaining Query syntax are working as lucene.net provide All query syntax (i.e Phrase syntax, Boolean Operators Syntax, Wildcard query)

Comment: This is not a solution.  What if @searchQuery = "Text +"?  Your regex handling is going to throw another ParseException.  If you have control over the construction of the query, the fix is there; otherwise the error should be returned to the caller.

Comment: @RamblinRose any example leads to solution please give answer below. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could use [QueryParser.Escape](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/da/d66/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_query_parsers_1_1_query_parser.html#a648ae6a6b1d598c0a799e3654c67e513) as well, and yes that takes care of it indeed.  I'm a curious sort and my experience nags me to ask: where is the "AND" originating? Are you indexing "and"?

Comment: you did not see  QueryParser.Escape in my question? i try this but not works in my scenario.

Comment: @RamblinRose if you have any solution for all scenario then give answer below will be appreciated.

Comment: I did not, I'm assuming it didn't work since "AND" isn't escaped unlike *, +, - etc.  Regardless if this satisfies your requirements then job done ;)

Comment: This won't work. The variable "cooked" is not declared or used in the query parser.